# Excel - Understanding a SUMPRODUCT formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this excel formula that someone has created without documentation and I'm struggling to understand it.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(-MID(TEXT(MID(TEXT(F2,REPT(0,15)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:15")),1)*{2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2},"00"),{1,2},1))
```

it looks like it creates a "random" digit from another number.
There are few key things I'm stuggling with:
* why is there an array (`{1,2}`) given to a `MID()` function?
* since there is a `SUMPRODUCT()`, which needs an array, I'm assuming that the result of the `-MID()` function is some sort of an array, how do I see what it is?
* what does multplying by an array {2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2} does?
* the `INDIRECT()` functions seems to always return 1?

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: The `INDIRECT(1:15)` returns an array of all the numbers from 1 to 15.  Each character in F2 is then multiplied by either 2 or 1 (alternating).  It looks like it calculates the check digit of a credit card number but I can test it because I only have my phone...

Comment: Agree with Jerry, it's for a credit card check digit, try googling "Luhn algorithm" or similar (although this calculation may be slightly different)

Answer (score 3):

There is a function in EXCEL called *Evaluate Formula*, a good tool to check the formula step by step.

### Assuming F2 is 123

1. `REPT(0,15)`

   Generate a string with 15 "0", that is `"000000000000000"`
2. `TEXT(F2,[1])`

   Convert F2 into a string with 15 char. Eg. `123 > "000000000000123"`
3. `ROW(INDIRECT("1:15"))`

   Return an array `{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15}`
4. `MID([2],[3],1)`

   Separate [2] into an array, each element is a char `{"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1";"2";"3"}`
5. `[4]*{2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2}`

   Since `{A;B} * {C;D} = {A*C;B*D}`

   `{"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"0";"1";"2";"3"}*{2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2;1;2}
   ={0*2;0*1;0*2;....}={0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;2;2;6}`
6. `TEXT([5],"00")`

   Converts the elements in the Array to two char by adding "0" in the front. The array goes to `{"00";"00";"00";"00";"00";"00";"00";"00";"00";"00";"00";"00";"02";"02";"06"}`
7. `MID([6],{1,2},1)`

   Note that {A,B} and {A;B} are different. {A,B} is an array with 1 row and 2 columns; {A;B} is an array with 2 rows and 1 column.

   In this formula, you can imagine doing MID twice, first time we use 1 as second parameter, second time we use 2 instead.

   The result is a 2-D array:
   `{"0","0";"0","0";"0","0";"0","0";"0","0";"0","0";"0","0";"0","0";"0","0";"0","0";"0","0";"0","0";"0","2";"0","2";"0","6"}`
8. `SUMPRODUCT(-[7])`

   The minus sign before [7] will force all elements in the array to convert to numbers with opposite sign.
   In this example, it sums `0+0+0+...+(-2)+0+(-2)+0+(-6) = -10`